# Make bootstrap carousel bullets slide another carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Based on the code from codrops from this page: [Codrops article](http://tympanus.net/Development/ItemTransitions/index3.html) , I wanted to add the product slider into a bootstrap carousel.

[I have added a codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYbPWK)

This is the javascript code that makes the bottles animation work:

```
(function() {
var support = { animations : Modernizr.cssanimations },
    animEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
        'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
        'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
        'animation' : 'animationend'
    },
    // animation end event name
    animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ],
    component = document.getElementById( 'products' ),
    items = component.querySelector( 'ul.itemwrap' ).children,
    current = 0,
    itemsCount = items.length,
    navNext = document.getElementById( 'move-right' ),
    navPrev = document.getElementById( 'move-left' ),
    navOne = document.getElementById( 'bullet-sl' )
    isAnimating = false;

function init() {
    navNext.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) { ev.preventDefault(); navigate( 'next' ); } );
    navPrev.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) { ev.preventDefault(); navigate( 'prev' ); } );
}

function navigate( dir ) {
    if( isAnimating ) return false;
    isAnimating = true;
    var cntAnims = 0;

    var currentItem = items[ current ];

    if( dir === 'next' ) {
        current = current < itemsCount - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
    }
    else if( dir === 'prev' ) {
        current = current > 0 ? current - 1 : itemsCount - 1;
    }

    var nextItem = items[ current ];

    var onEndAnimationCurrentItem = function() {
        this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndAnimationCurrentItem );
        classie.removeClass( this, 'current' );
        classie.removeClass( this, dir === 'next' ? 'navOutNext' : 'navOutPrev' );
        ++cntAnims;
        if( cntAnims === 2 ) {
            isAnimating = false;
        }
    }

    var onEndAnimationNextItem = function() {
        this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndAnimationNextItem );
        classie.addClass( this, 'current' );
        classie.removeClass( this, dir === 'next' ? 'navInNext' : 'navInPrev' );
        ++cntAnims;
        if( cntAnims === 2 ) {
            isAnimating = false;
        }
    }

    if( support.animations ) {
        currentItem.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndAnimationCurrentItem );
        nextItem.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndAnimationNextItem );
    }
    else {
        onEndAnimationCurrentItem();
        onEndAnimationNextItem();
    }

    classie.addClass( currentItem, dir === 'next' ? 'navOutNext' : 'navOutPrev' );
    classie.addClass( nextItem, dir === 'next' ? 'navInNext' : 'navInPrev' );


}

init();  })();
```

Everything is good when I'm using the arrows to go to the next slide, but what I'm trying to accomplish is to make it work with the bullet navigation on the bottom. Right now the bullet navigation only moves the slides from the bootstrap carousel and I find the code from codrops to be too difficult to understand for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simplified version of what you're trying to do

```js
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 3000
});

/* SLIDE ON CLICK */

$('.carousel-linked-nav > li > a').click(function() {

  // grab href, remove pound sign, convert to number
  var item = Number($(this).attr('href').substring(1));

  // slide to number -1 (account for zero indexing)
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(item - 1);

  // remove current active class
  $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');

  // add active class to just clicked on item
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');

  // don't follow the link
  return false;
});

/* AUTOPLAY NAV HIGHLIGHT */

// bind 'slid' function
$('#myCarousel').bind('slide', function() {

  // remove active class
  $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');

  // get index of currently active item
  var idx = $('#myCarousel .item.active').index();

  // select currently active item and add active class
  $('.carousel-linked-nav li:eq(' + idx + ')').addClass('active');

});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css');
 #myCarousel {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.carousel-linked-nav,
.item img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.carousel-linked-nav {
  width: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/ItemTransitions/img/9.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/ItemTransitions/img/10.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/ItemTransitions/img/11.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>

<!-- LINKED NAV -->
<ol class="carousel-linked-nav pagination">
  <li class="active"><a href="#1">&#8226;</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#2">&#8226;</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#3">&#8226;</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you Rachel for the help! However, the effect isn't exactly what I wanted .. I want the colour backgrounds to fade and the bottle to drop from top, preferably with the effect I had in my codepen. Sorry for not giving the exact details.

Comment: no problem. can you hover beside the answer and click the tick?

Comment: we both get points if you accept the answer, plus if this is your first accept you get a badge :) A bg check mark appears when you go down beside the answer and when you click it it turns green..

Comment: The solution you provided is the same as the default carousel on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel .

Comment: the point is that the bullets work. its the same principle. is there a special effect you want?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my first comment, I want the colour backgrounds to fade to each other and the bottle to drop from top, preferably with the effect I had in my codepen. Sorry for not giving the exact details.